# .htaccess url rewriting issue pointing different urls to same location

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website I want to point different URLS to same location for example

```
www.something.com/usa/?abc=4&test=34&size=small
www.something.com/denmark/?abc=4&test=34&size=small&abc2=4&test2=34&size2=small
```

Should point to
   www.something.com/index.php?abc=4&test=34&size=small
   www.something.com/index.php?abc=4&test=34&size=small&abc2=4&test2=34&size2=small

and so on

and yes i do need to track from which country the request came from

the querystring parameters can have any amount of different parameters

what I have so far is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?domain=$1 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

How can this be achieved?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code (QSA is important)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (?!^index\.php$)^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?domain=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Just keep in mind that above rule will forward every URI that is not already `/index.php` to `/index.php` and append existing query string with a new query parameter `domain=country`.